# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference - Event.ENTER_FRAME

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe, runtime-error

I am aware there are *tons* of answers to this problem, but after searching for a while. I could not find one. I know it has to do with my `Event.ENTER_SCENE`.

Here's my code:

```
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, touchBegin);
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE, touchMove);
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, touchEnd);

function touchBegin(e:TouchEvent){
    if(oCharUse == true){
    if(Math.abs(e.stageX - oChar.x) < 100 && Math.abs(e.stageY - oChar.y) < 100){
        oMove = true;
    }   }   }
function touchMove(e:TouchEvent){
    if(oCharUse == true){
    if(oMove == true){
    oChar.x = e.stageX;
    oChar.y = e.stageY - 100;
    }   }   }
function touchEnd(e:TouchEvent){
    if(oCharUse == true){
    oMove = false;
    }   }


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop)

    function loop (e:Event){

        if(_collisionTest.complex(x2x, oChar)){
            trace("collision")
            }


        }
```

I was told to add more info: The error refers to this line: `if(_collisionTest.complex(x2x2, oChar))`. _collisionTest, is a collisiondetectionkit I got off the internet. And it only appears twice in the code you see above. Not on any other frame.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the object what you're referencing is null, not defined at that point, provide the line number, because without that, we can't really help. We don't know what _collisionTest is, don't know where was it initiated. Provide more information please.

Comment: Line is this one: if(_collisionTest.complex(x2x2, oChar))                             _collisionTest, is a collisiondetectionkit I got off the internet. And it only appears twice in the code you see above. Not on any other frames

Comment: Well, don't really know what's happening there, the fact that it only appears twice is, well... interesting because that's an enterframe event and has nothing else in it... nest the if statement into another if statement which checks the _collisionTest. (whether it's null or not)

Comment: What is that x2x? Is that an object or a variable? Considering that oChar is an existing one, the x2x might cause the error then.

Comment: Would you recommend any other collision detections that are simpler. (Ones that work precisely. Not including hitTestObject or hitTestPoint). And what do you mean by"nest the if statement into another if statement which checks the _collisionTest. (whether it's null or not)"

Comment: x2x2 is just another instance. Similar to oChar

Comment: if(_collisionTest!=null){ [original if statement here] }

Comment: I still get the same error. EDIT: I commented out the other part if-statement (not the one you suggested to me). And I don't get an error.
EDIT 2: I put a trace() statement in the if-statement you suggested (which is in the EVENT_FRAME loop) but it does not trace anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the variable.

```
var _collisionTest:CollisionTest = new CollisionTest();
```